# Preventing function when scrolling to top of page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to prevent an HTML template I'm editing from enlarging the top navigation bar when scrolling back to the top.

I have been trying for a long while to pinpoint with Firebug where exactly I need to change something in the js or css, but I cannot seem to be able to put my finger on it.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding in !important on the style where it has padding: 15px 0; => padding: 15px 0 !important; This is for media="screen"
#primary {

Comment: Are you trying to pin the menu at the top? If so and you're using bootstrap, look for afix in its docs. And if you arent't maybe you should also look for it to see how it works.

Comment: http://demo.lovethem.es/extra_html/assets/js/application.js Line 34

Comment: Thanks so much, James Lalor, your suggestion did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

OK so without the actual code it's hard to see what's changing it. I mean I can pull the page's source code, but it's better if you simply provide it in case you have any server side code that could effect the outcome. Anyway, with that said I noticed that your header is being changed from `position: relative; padding: 30px` to `position: fixed; padding: 15px` and according to the console window on chrome these changes take place from the element's inline style. So I would recommend looking at your Javascript code. I quickly looked at it and it seems to be coming from the following file (again I seriously looked for less than a minute): application.js

```
nav.css({
 position   : 'relative',
 padding    : '30px 0',
 left       : nav.offset().left
});
```

So you should double check this section and others dealing with the nav.css to make sure it's doing what you want.

Comment: also I just noticed the comment by JFK. This also points you to the same file, and he is likely noticing the same change for nav.css where you alter it from being a padding of 15px to that of 30px.

Comment: Thank you. I added the '!important' tag to the application.css after the padding info, and it worked rigth away. I'm not sure why, but this somehow seals the 15px property.

Comment: It doesn't seal it, what's happening is a piece of java script code is adding inline css to the div, adding important on the style sheet makes it choose this as the css to listen to, rather than the inline code.